# On launch emacs makes "ding" sound and displays "<noname> is undefined" message

Tags: emacs

I was using a very old version of Emacs on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit so I upgraded to Emacs 25.3.1 64 bit.  The installation went well.

When I ran Emacs, I started reading the messages in the initial buffer and then I heard a "ding" sound and the message "<noname> is undefined" was displayed.

I started typing into the buffer and approximately 10 seconds after the first "ding" sound there was another and the message "<noname> is undefined" message was displayed again.

If I try to enter text into the buffer or enter a command, I'm interrupted by the "ding" and "<noname> is undefined" message.  This makes Emacs useless.

Thinking that perhaps there was something in my Emacs initialization file which is no longer valid, I closed Emacs and renamed the Emacs initialization file, then launched Emacs again.  Same "ding" sound and same message.

I'm not sure what "noname" Emacs is complaining about or how to fix it.  It is now almost 3 AM (US Eastern time) so I'm going to get some sleep and attack this in the daylight hours.

Oh!  One other thing - I access the Windows 7 Professional 64 bit box via Remote Desktop, as the computer is in a facility in another state.

Any idea as to what is going on?

---

More Information:
I rebooted after installing the new version of Emacs.  When the computer rebooted it automatically launched the DishAnywhere player.

Normally I kill the DishAnywhere player shortly after launch, but last night I didn't, so DishAnywhere was running when I launched Emacs.

Today I've run some experiments and found:

-- If DishAnywhere is running and I launch Emacs, Emacs will "Ding" and display the "<noname> is undefined" message every 10 seconds.

-- If I exit Emacs and kill off DishAnywhere, then launch Emacs, Emacs runs correctly - no "Ding" or error message.

-- If I launch DishAnywhere AFTER Emacs has started running, no "Ding" or error message.

-- If I then exit Emacs, wait a few minutes, and then launch Emacs again (while DishAnywhere is running), Emacs runs correctly - no "Ding" or error message.

So...

If DishAnywhere runs BEFORE Emacs is launched, Emacs has a problem, "Dings" and displays an error message.

If Emacs is launched BEFORE DishAnywhere and is running when DishAnywhere is launched, then Emacs runs correctly.

**The workaround is to:**

**Kill DishAnywhere before launching Emacs, then launch DishAnywhere.**

But the question is what is the interaction between DishAnywhere and Emacs that causes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If so then use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a recipe of what you are doing and what you see.

If not (which is what I'm guessing) then recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit code.  You can use command `comment-region` to comment out a block of code. If you use `C-u` with `comment-region` then it uncomments a block of code.

Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8, ... of your init file, to narrow the problematic part.  This is a binary search, so it is very quick to do, even if it means restarting Emacs multiple times.

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the response!  I tried "emacs -Q" but it had no effect.  As soon as the problem occurred I disabled the emacs initialization file, so at present there is none.  I'm going to try a few more things before submitting a bug report. Thanks for the help!  John

Comment: More Information:  The DishAnywhere player automatically starts on reboot, and I had rebooted after installing the new version of Emacs.  I know it causes problems with certain games (like Age of Empires HD).  I just noticed that I did not kill off the DishAnywhere player.  After a conference call I'll run some more experiments.